# Openshift deployment - fabric8 or template

Tags: openshift, fabric8, openshift-3, katacoda

I am new to openshift and was going through the interactive tutorialat https://learn.openshift.com/middleware/fis-deploy-app/.

This tutorial uses the source code from https://github.com/jbossdemocentral/katacoda-fuse-getting-started.git and builds the docker image and deploys the app to openshift environment.

I tempalte file mentioned in the tutorial defines the "Routes,Services,BuildConfig, etc" thats required for the deployment. However I could see them defined in /src/main/fabric folder too.

It looks like the fabric folder is not used in the build process. The Route,services,etc created/shown in Openshift console matches the template file.

Can someone clarify whats the use of fabric8 folder and the files inside? I am assuming there should be another way to create the app that takes the configurations from fabric8 - is this correct? Should template file refer to the configs in fabric8?

Can you share some good example which deploys the application into openshift using fabric8?

Basically I have springboot application in my local and trying to figure out the best deployment approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`/src/main/fabric8` folder is only used by fabric8. Files in this folder are called "resource fragments", in which you can customize kubernetes resource definiton. For example, [this resource fragment](http://maven.fabric8.io/#resource-fragments) enriches default fabric8 deployment with custom volumes, environment variables and service account.

The following configuration in `pom.xml` is required to deploy application into openshift using fabric8 maven plugin.

```
<properties>
    <fabric8.mode>openshift</fabric8.mode>
    <!-- Modify this configration as your openshift project name -->
    <fabric8.namespace>THE_OPENSHIFT_PROJECT_TO_DEPLOY</fabric8.namespace>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then, run `mvn fabric8:deploy` to deploy packaged jar file.

For more details, please refer to [fabric8 maven plugin](http://maven.fabric8.io).

Comment: I got fabric8 maven plugin in local machine. Should fabric8 be installed on top of openshift ? Am connecting to openshift env remotely.

Comment: You dont need fabric8 on OpenShift. You can connect directly. Before that run `oc login <hopenshift host>`